# Программа вылетает в дизассемблированный код

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Подскажите способы диагностики. Начинает открываться окно (WPF), срабатывает конструктор, срабатывает `OnLoad`, начинают срабатывать `CanExecute` команд, начинают отрабатывать конвертеры... Короче все идет к открытию окна. Но потом неожиданно все падает, открывается вкладка с дизассемблированным кодом и вот это исключение

> Дополнительные сведения: Нельзя задать Visibility или вызвать Show, ShowDialog или WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle после закрытия окна.

Проблема в том, что это не на какой то конкретной строке возникает, то есть я не могу отладить это. Вылетает рандомно. Иногда я даже успеваю увидеть форму, но чаще всего нет.

`OnClosing` не выполняется

**UPD:**

Стек при падении

> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.VerifyCanShow()
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
>   DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v15.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Core.FloatingWindowContainer.TryAsyncShowModal.AnonymousMethod__0()
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
>   source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs,
>   System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state)
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr
>   hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool
>   handled) WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr
>   hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool
>   handled)
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object
>   o)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
>   source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs,
>   System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
>   priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object
>   args, int numArgs)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
>   priority, System.Delegate method, object arg)
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr
>   hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) [Переход от
>   машинного кода к управляемому] [Переход от управляемого кода к
>   машинному]
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(ref
>   System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
>   ignore)
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
>   window) ClientOperator223.exe!ClientOperator223.App.Main() [Переход от
>   машинного кода к управляемому] [Переход от управляемого кода к
>   машинному]
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state) mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Найти, где вызывается указанные методы/свойства и понять почему они срабатывают после закрытия окна. Рандом скорее всего из-за того что что-то долго отрабатывает, а иногда быстро.

Comment: Добавь логгирование исключений со стеком, там и видно будет, кто вызвал и почему.

Comment: А у вас unsafe-кода в проекте нет?

Comment: а у Вас окно создаётся как-то нестандартно? Вы сами вызываете `Show` у окна?

Comment: @Monk, а можно подробнее? Где и как?

Comment: @VladD, не знаю. Ошибка вызвана где то во внутренностях DevExpress. Что там есть одному дъяволу известно (который курирует DevExpress). Вопрос был задан 2 раза на их форуме, но в обоих случаях ответа нет. В стек трейсе при этом одним из последних висит вот это   DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v15.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Core.FloatingWindowContainer.TryAsyncShowModal.AnonymousMethod__0()
последняя строка вот  PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.VerifyCanShow() и при этом в стектрейсе нет белых строк (то есть с моим проектом связано только App.Main())

Comment: Добавьте стек целиком в сообщение, если есть возможность. Иначе ловите событие `Application.UnhandledException` и его пишите в файл, оттуда скопируйте.

Comment: @Monk, добавил.

Comment: Результат асинхронного модального диалога кто-то ждёт в `app.xaml.cs`? Если нет, то он сразу и пытается закрыться, скорее всего.

Comment: @Monk Там нет никакого явного модального диалога. Вообще там кое что запускается асинхронно, но как мне увидеть в отладке все потоки и пошагово следить за выбранным потоком?

Comment: Поставьте бряк где начинается ваш поток и следите.

Comment: @Monk, там порождается много потоков. Они, как бы это сказать, расслаиваются

Comment: Вызывая `Show` или меняя `Visible` - поставьте проверку `IsWindow` или `Hanlde!=null`.